# Buddy Allocation Algorithm - Heap Extension

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, memory, memory-management

This is a second inquiry towards my implementation of a Buddy Allocation scheme, the first question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674763/buddy-allocation-algorithm-beginning-heap-address), which also explains what Buddy Allocation actually is. In the standard implementation, one starts with a large block of 2^i where i is an integer, which works with a static heap size (the entire heap is the largest block in this case).

My question hinges on an implementation that deals with a dynamically sizing heap, where the heap size starts at 0. Currently, when the highest order *i*, cannot find a block in a free list (a list of free blocks), I make a call to extend the heap size in order to appropriate this highest order block.

The problem is that I am not sure if this derivative breaks the invariant within the buddy system, which is the calculation of the buddy block's address given an address. This simply can be computed via flipping the ith order bit. The explanation of this calculation is in my previous question. When I implement this scheme sometimes I return the wrong buddy address.

Comment: Which call do you make in order to increase the heap size?

Comment: @fvdalcin It's a custom call, all it does is move the pointer to the back of the heap further back by a size argument, and returns a void pointer to the first address in this new allocated block.

Comment: AFAIK the buddy scheme assumes that the heap is contiguous. In general, expanding the heap either breaks that invariant or has to move the existing part of the heap and update all pointers, which is not possible in most environments (those where you can identify *all* pointers and update them to refer to the new heap region).

Comment: @delnan Even if you expand the heap only by a fixed amount that is the size of the max order each time? Wouldn't this create two separate "buddy-trees"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not absolutely sure if you can increase the heap size **after** some blocks have already been allocated. I think you will have to increase your heap and reallocate all the blocks again, following the allocation algorithm, but now considering your new heap size.

Answer (score 1):

```
    #include <stdio.h>

typedef struct X 
{
    unsigned int address;
    int empty;
    int id_req;//id_req
    int allow;
} Block;

typedef struct Y  
{
    int enz;
    int id_req;//req_id
    int ok;
} Defer;

unsigned int block_sizes[8] = {0};
unsigned int memSize;
unsigned int allcSize;

Block blocks[8][128];
int num_blocks[8];

int defer_pointer = 0;
Defer defers[100];

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int x, y, z; 

    for(x = 0;x < 100;x++)
        defers[x].ok = 1;

    for(x = 0;x < 8;x++)
        for(y = 0;y < 128;y++)
            blocks[x][y].empty = blocks[x][y].allow = 0;

    scanf("%u", &memSize);
    scanf("%u", &allcSize);

    block_sizes[0] = allcSize;
    for(x = 0;x+1 < 8;x++)
        if(block_sizes[x] == memSize)
            break;
        else
            block_sizes[x+1] = block_sizes[x]*2;

    blocks[x][0].address = 0;
    blocks[x][0].empty = 1;
    num_blocks[x] = 1;
    for(;x > 0;x--)
    {
        num_blocks[x-1] = num_blocks[x]*2;

        for(y=0;y < num_blocks[x];y++)
        {
            blocks[x-1][2*y].address = blocks[x][y].address;
            blocks[x-1][2*y+1].address = blocks[x][y].address + block_sizes[x-1];
        }
    }

    while(scanf("%d", &z) != EOF)
    {
        char op = getchar();
        while(op != '-' && op != '+') op = getchar();

        if(op == '+')
        {
            unsigned int size;
            scanf("%u", &size);
            printf("Request ID %d: allocates %u byte%s.\n", z, size, size == 1 ? "" : "s");

            int enz = 0;
            while(block_sizes[enz] < size)
                enz++;

            unsigned int address;
            if(allocate(enz, z, &address)) 
            {
                printf("\tSuccess; addr = 0x%08x.\n", address);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\tRequest deferred.\n");
                defers[defer_pointer].ok = 0;
                defers[defer_pointer].enz = enz;
                defers[defer_pointer].id_req = z;
                defer_pointer++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Request ID %d: deallocate.\n", z);

            int success = 0;
            for(x = 0;x < 8 && block_sizes[x] != 0 && success != 1;x++)
                for(y = 0;y < num_blocks[x] && success != 1;y++)
                    if(blocks[x][y].allow)

                        if (blocks[x][y].id_req == z)
                        {
                            blocks[x][y].allow = 0;
                            blocks[x][y].empty = 1;
                            success = 1;
                        }

            x--;y--;

            if(success)
                printf("\tSuccess.\n");
            else
                continue;
            // the buddy system

            while(x < 8 && num_blocks[x] > 1)
            {
                int buddy = (blocks[x][y].address / block_sizes[x]) %2 == 0 ? (y+1) : (y-    1);

                if(blocks[x][buddy].empty)
                {
                    blocks[x][y].empty = 0;
                    blocks[x][buddy].empty = 0;

                    blocks[x+1][y/2].empty = 1;
                    x++;
                    y /= 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            for(x = 0;x < defer_pointer;x++)
                if(!defers[x].ok)
                {
                    unsigned int address;
                    if(allocate(defers[x].enz, defers[x].id_req, &address))
                    {
                        defers[x].ok = 1;
                        printf("\tDeferred request %d allocated; addr = 0x%08x\n", defers[x].id_req, address);
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int allocate(int enz, int id_req, unsigned int *address)
{
    int x, y, ret = 0;
    for(x = enz;x < 8 && block_sizes[x] != 0 && ret == 0;x++)
        for(y = 0;y < num_blocks[x] && ret == 0;y++)
            if(blocks[x][y].empty)
                ret = 1;
    x--;y--;
    if(ret == 0)
        return 0;

    while(x != enz)
    {
        blocks[x][y].empty = 0;

        blocks[x-1][2*y].empty = 1;
        blocks[x-1][2*y+1].empty = 1;

        x = x-1;
        y = 2*y;
    }

    blocks[x][y].empty = 0;
    blocks[x][y].id_req = id_req;
    blocks[x][y].allow = 1;
    *address = blocks[x][y].address;
}
```

Comment: The program above shows a basic implementation of the buddy system within which heap extension on buddy allocation is shown.

Comment: Hopefully it might be of help to someone